# Android: What application started my Application?

Tags: android

In Android app how programmatically discover what app has started my app?

I think it should be in MyApplication that extends `Application`, but [it has no clues](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html).

However inside Activity I could call [`getIntent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)
and if the calling app is polite to give such info, I would get it via
`intent.getStringExtra()`

**Is there general approach that would not have requirements for calling apps to provide self info?**

In other app developer would call as

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.company.myapp");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

see [Launch an application from another application on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android) and [Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent)

UPDATE: I have wrote an app that launches my app and indeed the only way is to put Extra data into Intent as the intent has only `"android.intent.action.MAIN"` , `"android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"` and package of launched app.

Comment: I think it's impossible, at least according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199727/android-find-the-sender-of-an-intent-for-a-monitoring-application).