# Android: Get Intent despite calling finish() on the previous Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

My use-case is as follows:

In activity A I call:

```
startActivity(B);
finish();
```

Now in onCreate of Activity B I need to know the activity that started B, so I wonder if in onCreate(...) of Activity B I call:

```
getIntent();
```

Would I even be able to get the Intent that started Activity B or would getIntent() at that point already return null because I finished Activity A immediately after calling startActivity(B) ?

Comment: you can pass activity name by caliing intent.putExtra("AvtiVityName","Activity A")

Comment: Woudln't it be worth trying it ? lol

Comment: but your Activity A finish after starting Activity B so getIntent(); always give value you have send  from Activity A. try it.

Comment: @Snicolas well thing is; I wanted to know a bit of background information about it :) plus: I am working on a massive framework - so if I want to try the above I'd have to change a lot, just to see if it could work. So I'd rather know before I try.

Comment: @imrankhan Thanks I thought so, but I wasnt sure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find Intent source in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789155/how-to-find-intent-source-in-android)

Comment: @Snicolas Basically true, except that the important part here was the call to finish() which wasn't quite clear to me in regard to the order of execution. I searched for the same use-case as mine but did not find a suitable question/answer, so I posted it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class); 
intent.putExtra("activityStarted", "A");
```

and in Activity B

```
String started = getIntent().getExtras().getString("activityStarted");
```

Comment: same as the first comment on the OP, but yeah easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

In first activity use below code to start new activity and restart method() to finish the activity::

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ThisActivity.this, NextActivity.class); 
intent.putExtra("Key", "Value");
startActivity(intent);

@Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestart();
        finish();
    }
```

In Second activity::

```
String started = getIntent().getStringExtras("Key");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - but what would be the purpose of calling finish() in onRestart? Isn't that rather dangerous?

Comment: did that coz as your you want to finish the current activity. so i done when you return from activity and it is not dangerous

Comment: Thank you Agarwal Shankar, it's useful for my menu system