# Intent result, how to know who sent it?

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to know which package or process sent the Intent result?

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
```

I found a way to know which apps are capable of handling this intent, but I also want to know which one was selected, or rather, which one returned the result. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find Intent source in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789155/how-to-find-intent-source-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on apps how they are developed. 
Some apps returns an Intent object full of stuff, other empty or null.

```
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent i) {
         if (i!=null){        
            i.getPackage();
            i.getExtras();
            i.getData();
            i.getScheme();
            i.getType();
           }
        }
```

Try to log/read all possible values inside [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try looking at the `Logcat`.It contains information about when the intent started and how.I have tried using it to know whether an intent starts or not.