# How to get package name of the source APP that calls my exported Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an exported Activity in my APP to provide login service for third party APPs, they call startActivityForResult() to launch the exported Activity in my APP. Is there any way to get the package name of source APP which calls my Activity?  (put extra in intent is not capable because it's easy to fake)

thx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2780475/1576416 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/3304374/1576416

Comment: `String packageName= getCallingActivity().getPackageName();` use this in your exported activity.