# Can we know the class name of the activity that started the current?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Is there a way to know which activity class started another activity class other than passing the name of the class as an `Extra` in the `Intent`?
When we do `new Intent(this, SomeOtherActivity.class)`  is it possible to get the name of `this` in the when we are in `onCreate` of the `SomeOtherActivity`?

Comment: Seems like you are a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304304/how-to-get-the-sender-of-an-intent - recommending close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an instance and put an extra to the intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SomeOtherActivity.class)
i.putExtra("ACTIVITY_NAME", this.getClass().getName());
```

Retrieve it with:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String activityName = extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
```

Comment: So the framework does not offer this information? I have to explicitly pass it?

Comment: AFAIK yes, you should because intent doesn't. Also cant find nothing in [Intent API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). But not 100% sure... let's wait if there are other answers. Have you debugged @ `onCreate` searching for the context?