# Android - Intent Sharing

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

How to detect from which (any) external app(or packagname) data was shared:

Via sharing an image/data (intent) from another app to my app(activity),

Comment: Please explain more so that people can understand what you are really saying

Comment: AFAIK, this is not supported.

Comment: It is straight forward, e.g you shared a photo from Gallery with your App, how you can detect that the photo is shared from the gallery app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the sender of an Intent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304304/how-to-get-the-sender-of-an-intent)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void shareImage() {
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    // If you want to share a png image only, you can do:
    // setType("image/png"); OR for jpeg: setType("image/jpeg");
    share.setType("image/*");

    // Make sure you put example png image named myImage.png in your
    // directory
    String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/myImage.png";

    File imageFileToShare = new File(imagePath);

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image!"));
}
```