# Android how to hide intent sender package?

Tags: android

App package name A, send intent with action ACTION_VIEW and url data to system, app B get it and open, but I just want B open intent and don't want app B get app A's package name, How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to find out the package that sent the Intent seems to be via [`Acitvity#getReferrer()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getReferrer()) (taken from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37761737)). In its docs, the following is clearly stated

> Return information about who launched this activity. If the launching Intent contains an [`Intent.EXTRA_REFERRER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#EXTRA_REFERRER), that will be returned as-is; otherwise, if known, an `Intent#URI_ANDROID_APP_SCHEME` referrer URI containing the package name that started the Intent will be returned. This may return null if no referrer can be identified -- it is neither explicitly specified, nor is it known which application package was involved.

Hence you can add `Intent.EXTRA_REFERRER` to the intents you're sending to override the default value.

---

#### Ref

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37761737
2. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getReferrer()
3. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#EXTRA_REFERRER