# Get application name which invoked the intent in android

Tags: java, android

I have two apps, say App A and App B, App A call tries to invoke a service in App B using intent, I don't want to allow App A if it does not belong to a certain list of allowed app names, is there a way to find out the name of the app which is calling my service in App B.

PS: I am using AIDL bound service to communicate between the two apps, App A has an activity that calls upon service in App B, getReferrer() is not available in service, I have checked with API level 22 also.

Comment: You could try to use a `referrer` (since API 22) as mentioned in [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67552933/1712135)…

Comment: @deHaar I have updated my question, can u please suggest a solution for this, I am trying to access it inside a service and there is no getReferrer functionality available in there.

Comment: Are you an owner of both apps?

Comment: @OleksiiK. , I own only App B, I need package name of caller(App A) for security purposes

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AIDL you can define your service so that it receives a name or secret key and check if the client is valid then respond to it.

Comment: Does android provide functionality for extracting service invoker identity, I would like to skip the harder security implementations.

Comment: As far as I know Android doesn't provide such functionality.