# Get package name of the browser which invokes the app then invoke the browser

Tags: java, android

My app can currently invoked by all browsers, however there is a requirement that I need to open a webpage in the browser which initially invokes my application.

While the solutions from [How can I open a URL in Android's web browser from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application) can launch an intent and let the user choose which browser to response to the intent. I want to let the app opens the same browser that the user previously used to invoke my application (by clicking a web link) so that the user won't be confused and leading to better user experience.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [https://stackoverflow.com/a/37761737/10317684](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37761737/10317684) [getReferrer()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getReferrer())

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that you can get the name of the calling application. Because the browser you are talking about may not start your application  with `startActivityForResult`
however if it did you can get it's package name by

```
getActivity().getCallingPackage()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://"));
ResolveInfo resolveInfo = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(browserIntent,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

// This is the default browser's packageName
String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;